# Authorization in HyperLedger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

What is best way to implement authorization in applications build on Hyperledger Fabric?

Consider the Marbles demo use case from here: https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles

How/Where should I implement the following functionality?

- Only admin user be able to create and allocate new marbles
- Users (Amy, Alice, Ava from this example) should be only allowed to transfer out the marbles that they own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you need to consider leveraging `GetCreator` API to extract certificate of the client which created transaction proposal. Once you will obtain certificate you can implement desired functionality, e.g.:

> - Only admin user be able to create and allocate new marbles
> - Users (Amy, Alice, Ava from this example) should be only allowed to transfer out the marbles that they own

Here is the example of how to desirialize certificate within chaincode:

```
func (*smartContract) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response {
    fmt.Println("Invoke")

    serializedID, _ := stub.GetCreator()

    sId := &msp.SerializedIdentity{}
    err := proto.Unmarshal(serializedID, sId)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Could not deserialize a SerializedIdentity, err %s", err))
    }

    bl, _ := pem.Decode(sId.IdBytes)
    if bl == nil {
        return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Could not decode the PEM structure"))
    }
    cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(bl.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("ParseCertificate failed %s", err))
    }

    fmt.Println(cert)

    return shim.Success(nil)
}
```