# Hyperledger Fabric NodeJS Chaincode - Retrieve caller identifier

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to develop a chaincode which has to create and store a car object and allows to transfer the ownership of the car.

When the "createCar" is invoked, I would like to set the owner of the car to the identifier/certificate of who submit the transaction.

I'm also developing a method that allows to transfer the ownership of the car. In this method I would like to insert a condition which raise an exception if the current user (who invoked the transaction) is not the current owner of the car.

```
//arg[0]=identifier - arg[1]=model
async createCar(stub, args) {
  console.info('============= START : Create Car ===========');
  if (args.length != 2) {
    throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 2');
  }

  console.info("Creator",stub.getCreator());

  var car = {
    model: arg[1],
    owner: //.... - Here store the id of who invoked the transaction
  };

  await stub.putState(args[0], Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(car)));

  console.info('============= END : Create Car ===========');

  return true;
}
```

---

```
//arg[0]=identfier - arg[1] = New owner
async transferCar(stub,args){
    let carAsBytes = await stub.getState(arg[0]);
    let car = JSON.parse(carAsBytes);

    if (car.owner != /*... - new user that invoked the transaction*/) {
        throw new Error('Invalid owner');
    }

    car.owner = arg[1];

    await stub.putState(args[0], Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(car)));

    return true;
}
```

Does anyone know what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the getCreator() which will return identity object of the chaincode invocation's submitter.

Comment: Thanks. How can I compare the owner once has been store by using getCreator()?

    if (car.owner != /*... - new user that invoked the transaction*/) {
        throw new Error('Invalid owner');
    }

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591996/authorization-in-hyperledger-fabric]  this might help you, something similar to your requirements. in your case you just have to check submitter and the current owner is same or not.